# Where is Siri finding this event?

Tags: mail.app, calendar, siri

I wrote this email to my sister earlier this week. However, it shows that "Siri found an event." Not only that, it found a time. How did this happen?

For context, here's the email. (I didn't remove anything. I trust the internet a little more than I should.)[image]

Comment: "We're probably going to place a game of Cantan later" That's my guess. Siri doesn't always get things right, I wouldn't worry too much about a false positive.

Comment: But tomorrow at 9:00? I didn't say anything about any time anywhere.

Comment: It might have assumed that the day starts at 9am. (I sure wish it did.)